# Error when trying to make SQL Server database connection in Java code

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I'm fairly new to coding for database connections and running queries and all that. I've looked over some tutorials and examples and I feel like I've got 95% of this done correctly but there's gotta be something small I'm missing.

I'm currently trying to make a connection to a SQL Server database and I keep getting the exception:

> This driver is not configured for integrated authentication.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
try {
        String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://serverName;DatabaseName=database;integratedSecurity=true";
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "username", "password");
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs;

        rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from database.dbo.table\n" +
                "  where column = 2785 \n" +
                "  AND anotherColumn = 3");
        while ( rs.next() ) {
            String condition = rs.getString("Condition");
            System.out.println(condition);
        }
        conn.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

I think I'm running into an issue because our databases use Windows Auth. Here's what that looks like when I log into Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio:

[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you have "the sqljdbc_auth.dll file to a directory on the Windows system path on the computer where the JDBC driver is installed" ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url#Connectingintegrated

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the [MSDN Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url) to resolve your problems with `Integrated Authentication` via `JDBC`.

Two things to keep in mind when you try this out:

- To use integrated authentication, copy the `sqljdbc_auth.dll` file to a directory on the Windows system path on the computer where the JDBC driver is installed.
- If you are running a 32-bit Java Virtual Machine (JVM), use the `sqljdbc_auth.dll` file in the x86 folder, even if the operating system is the x64 version. If you are running a 64-bit JVM on a x64 processor, use the `sqljdbc_auth.dll` file in the x64 folder.

Hope this helps you resolve your issue.